# Anyway to keep/stick a "file tab" at the front

Tags: development-environment, textmate

I have a few files that i am working on in any given moment that i would love to have at the front of my tabs at any given moment. How can I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can drag tabs in whatever order you'd like and then access them directly with Command + 1-9